# How to get Last post Id of custom post type in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts

I want to get last post id of a custom post type in wordpress. For this I tried this code-

```
args = array(
    'post_type' =>'soto_property',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'=>'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
     );

   $image_posts = get_posts($args);
   foreach ( $image_posts  as $post )
   {
       echo $post->ID;
   }
```

But It always returns me the First post id of this custom post type.I have tried `'order'=>'ASC'` also but it gives me same result.

How can I achieve the last post id of this CPT.

Comment: So `'order' => 'ASC'` and `'order => 'DESC'` return the same post ID?

Comment: `post_date` should be `date`

Comment: I replaced `'post_date'` with `'date'` but it didn't work. also `order=>'ASC'` and `order=>'DESC'` giving same result